# Objective function in linked prediction models

Tags: r, optimization, function

I would like to use R “optimize” function to estimate the model:

$\hat{Y_{t}}=a\cdot \hat{Y}_{t-1}+b\cdot X_{t}+c\cdot X_{t-1}$

Important thing is that the predition $\hat{Y_{t}}$ (let’s say prediction of Y on Tuesday) is calculated on the basis of former prediction $\hat{Y}_{t-1}$ (not real value of $Y_{t-1}$) in time t-1 (Monday).

**What is key word to google to find out more on this class of models? I mean time series models where prediction is based on former prediction, not actual value like in ARIMA models.**

With an objective function I would like to minimize the sum of the squares of the errors between ${Y_{t}}$ and $\hat{Y}_{t}$. The objective function in one equation would look like endless spaghetti.

How to write objective function in R?

Comment: This sounds like an ARIMA model.

Comment: Maybe it sounds like ARIMA, but it ain't. ARIMA is easier to estimate because the forecast refers to previous real Y which is fixed. In my problem you refer to previous forecasted Y which changes anytime the parameters of the model change.

Comment: Your link does not work. Please provide the referred material in a form that enables users to see it if it is important for understanding your problem - i.e. perfectly data and the code in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily estimate this model using R function which is `optim()` or using simple `lm()` function in iterative manner, first you suppress `Y(t-1)` by setting `a=0` then estimate `b` and `c`, this is first iteration, the next step is to add `Y(t-1)` as independent variable and estimate `Y(t)` once again, and again put `Y(t)` as  `Y(t-1)`; notice that by `Y(t)` I meant fitted variable in vector notation